# A probably simple big $\mathcal{O}$ question

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

I have a probably simple big $\mathcal{O}$ question.

Is the following statement correct?

$$\mathcal{O}(x \log x)=\mathcal{O}(\sqrt x \log x)$$

why?

Comment: If you divide one by the other, what do you get? What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $x\log x\in O(x\log x)$ (that shold be obvious), but assume that $x\log x\in O(\sqrt{x}\log x)$, then there exist $N$ and $y$ such that for $x>y$:
$$x\log x < N\sqrt{x}\log x$$ but that means that for $x>y$:
$$x < N\sqrt{x}$$
but then choose $x>N^2$.